# Tracking signs in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python 3.8.5 and numpy 1.18.5. I have, an example of two 5 x 3 np arrays as follows:

```
x
'''
array([[ 0.61671909, -3.28907688,  1.47162381],
       [-0.52380408, -0.87605603,  2.09490614],
       [-1.12907555,  0.00810023,  0.41001445],
       [-1.12316108, -0.93468271, -0.41353168],
       [-1.14203546,  0.0319224 ,  1.04925758]])
'''

y
'''
array([[-0.19258918,  0.24449053, -1.16664036],
       [-0.00495552, -1.12518086,  0.30846267],
       [-1.09738445,  1.96309078, -0.67126134],
       [-0.93575175, -0.17778996,  3.15546178],
       [ 0.73158413,  1.09391779,  0.73405069]])
'''
```

I want to keep track of how many of the individual (element-wise) numbers **change sign** from 'x' to 'y'. For example, x[0][0] changes from positive to negative in the corresponding y[0][0].

I want to compute some statistics such as: "how many of the positive numbers changed to negative from x to y", "how many of the negative numbers changed to positive from x to y", etc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sign` function:

```
np.sign(x) != np.sign(y)
```

If you want the coordinates, you can wrap that around `np.where` or `np.nonzero`

```
np.where(np.sign(x)!=np.sign(y))
```

If you want the total number, just `sum`:

```
np.sum(np.sign(x) != np.sign(y))
# out  6
```

---

**Update** for the updated question:

```
signs = np.sign(x) - np.sign(y)

neg2pos = np.sum( signs == -2 ) 
pos2neg = np.sum( signs == 2 )
```

Comment: This won't work for me since I want to compute some statistics such as: "how many of the positive numbers changed to negative from x to y", "how many of the negative numbers to positive from x to y", etc.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to reflect that. An example of the output you'd like to achieve from your given input would help.

Comment: Editing my question

Comment: @QuangHoang OP wants distinct counts of each single shifts ('-' -> '+' and '+' -> '-'), not a total count of shifts.

Comment: @mathfux that was the updated question. Answer also updated.